# changing views causes audio engine to glitch out

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio, computer-science

I'm making an app that uses the audio engine and dictation to interpret what a user is saying. I have two views that I change between using the pushViewController method under the class UINavigationController: the home view controller (called "ViewController") and the graph view controller (called "GraphViewController"). When I change views and return from the GraphViewController to the ViewController, the audio engine begins completing buffers unreasonably fast (~10ms) and refuses to record any sound.

Note: The audio engine is set up in my ViewController class, the home view of my app.

Here are some error snippets to better explain my problem:

```
authorized
2021-03-28 01:14:29.631330-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935105] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6000032fb1e0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2021-03-28 01:14:29.797620-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935239] [aurioc] 323: Unable to join I/O thread to workgroup ((null)): 2
Text: Hello
Text: Hello hello
Text: Hello hello hello
Text: Hello hello hello
Text: Hello hello hello
Text: Hello hello hello this
Text: Hello hello hello this is
Text: Hello hello hello this is working
Text: Hello hello hello this is working normally
Text: Hello hello hello this is working normally
```

When the app launches, the home view controller (ViewController) loads and the audio engine begins recording. Everything works normally, and the buffers fill around every 30 seconds.

When I navigate to the GraphViewController (through the use of a button on the ViewController) the audio engine continues buffering normally. However, when I return to the ViewController using the "<Back" button in the top left corner of the view, the audio engine begins to glitch out and fill buffers every ~10ms:

```
2021-03-28 01:15:10.643091-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935105] Words successfully saved.
2021-03-28 01:15:10.644663-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4936029] [aurioc] 323: Unable to join I/O thread to workgroup ((null)): 2
2021-03-28 01:15:10.654050-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935938] [Utility] +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"
completed buffer
2021-03-28 01:15:10.674991-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935105] Words successfully saved.
2021-03-28 01:15:10.676519-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4936031] [aurioc] 323: Unable to join I/O thread to workgroup ((null)): 2
2021-03-28 01:15:10.683803-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935215] [Utility] +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"
completed buffer
2021-03-28 01:15:10.706812-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935105] Words successfully saved.
2021-03-28 01:15:10.708591-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4936032] [aurioc] 323: Unable to join I/O thread to workgroup ((null)): 2
2021-03-28 01:15:10.718311-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935936] [Utility] +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"
completed buffer
2021-03-28 01:15:10.741680-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935105] Words successfully saved.
2021-03-28 01:15:10.743231-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4936033] [aurioc] 323: Unable to join I/O thread to workgroup ((null)): 2
2021-03-28 01:15:10.754336-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935939] [Utility] +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"
completed buffer
2021-03-28 01:15:10.774254-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935105] Words successfully saved.
2021-03-28 01:15:10.775783-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4936034] [aurioc] 323: Unable to join I/O thread to workgroup ((null)): 2
2021-03-28 01:15:10.787332-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935938] [Utility] +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=209 "(null)"
completed buffer
2021-03-28 01:15:10.814357-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4935105] Words successfully saved.
2021-03-28 01:15:10.815785-0400 DictoCounter[24060:4936035] [aurioc] 323: Unable to join I/O thread to workgroup ((null)): 2
```

This is clearly a problem as the buffer cannot receive any audio input if the audio engine only records for short bursts of time. I've searched this error in other stack overflow posts, as well as the iOS forums, but no one seems to have the same changing-views problem that I have. I'll paste relevant code below:

```
//AUDIO ENGINE- inside ViewController
    func recognizeAudioStream() {
        let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
        
        //performs speech recognition on live audio; as audio is captured, call append
        //to request object, call endAudio() to end speech recognition
        var recognitionRequest: SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?
        
        //determines & edits state of speech recognition task (end, start, cancel, etc)
        var recognitionTask: SFSpeechRecognitionTask?
        
        let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
        
        
        func startRecording() throws{
            
            //cancel previous audio task
            recognitionTask?.cancel()
            recognitionTask = nil
            
            //get info from microphone
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .measurement, options: .duckOthers)
            try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
            
            let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
            
            //audio buffer; takes a continuous input of audio and recognizes speech
            recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
            //allows device to print results of your speech before you're done talking
            recognitionRequest?.shouldReportPartialResults = true
            
            
            recognitionTask = speechRecognizer!.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest!) {result, error in
                
                var isFinal = false
                
                if let result = result{ //if we can let result be the nonoptional version of result, then
                    isFinal = result.isFinal
                    print("Text: \(result.bestTranscription.formattedString)")
                    
                }
                
                if error != nil || result!.isFinal{ //if an error occurs or we're done speaking
                    
                    audioEngine.stop()
                    inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
                    
                    recognitionTask = nil
                    recognitionRequest = nil

                    let bufferText = result?.bestTranscription.formattedString.components(separatedBy: (" "))
                    print("completed buffer")
                    
                    self.addToDictionary(wordNames: bufferText)
                    
                    sortedWordsDict = wordsDict.sorted {
                        return $0.value > $1.value
                    }
                    
                    allWords = [] //reset the array to reload words
                    
                    for (wordKey, countValue) in sortedWordsDict{
                        allWords.append(Word(word: wordKey, count: countValue))
                    }
                    
                    self.saveWords() //saves allWords list to file
                    
                    tempWords = Array(allWords.prefix(numWords)) //only show first 50 words
                    
                    wordsColl.reloadData()
//
                    do{
                        try startRecording()
                    }
                    catch{
                        print(error)
                    }
                    
                }
            
            }
            
            //configure microphone; let the recording format match with that of the bus we are using
            let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
            
            //contents of buffer will be dumped into recognitionRequest and into result, where
            //it will then be transcribed and printed out
            //1024 bytes = dumping "limit": once buffer fills to 1024 bytes, it is appended to recognitionRequest
            inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
                recognitionRequest?.append(buffer)
            }
            
            audioEngine.prepare()
            try audioEngine.start()
        }
        
        do{
            try startRecording()
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
        }
        
        
    }
```

The do-catch statement at the bottom ensures that the microphone keeps recording sound from the user. This has worked for me (other in this instance, where changing views seems to glitch the audio engine out). I have not found any better way to implement this continue-recording feature, so please let me know if there is a more efficient way! Moving on,

```
//INSIDE ViewController
 @objc func goToHome(){
        let homeView = ViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(homeView, animated: true)
    }
    
    @objc func goToGraph(){
        print("pressed")
        let graphView = GraphViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(graphView, animated: true)
    }
```

These functions control the pushing of the views. Finally, here is my SceneDelegate.swift relevant code:

```
//INSIDE SceneDelegate.swift
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene{
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            
            let viewController = ViewController()
            window.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

This piece of code inside the main class ViewController calls recognizeAudioStream():

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        wordsColl.reloadData()
        let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()
        requestDictAccess();
        
        if speechRecognizer!.isAvailable { //if the user has granted permission
            speechRecognizer?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition = true //for offline data
            
            recognizeAudioStream()
        }
        
    }
```

Thank you for reading this post! Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Please don’t post pictures of code, even console output. Copy it and paste it as text.

Comment: Where is the code that calls recognizeAudioStream? Did I miss it?

Comment: Sorry about that! I've edited my submission to these specifications. I also forgot to include the piece of code that calls recognizeAudioStream, so I included it at the bottom of my post. It's called by the viewDidAppear() function

Comment: Ah- and it appears I've found my problem! The reason why it was glitching out was because the `recognizeAudioStream()` function was being called every time the view "appeared," which in the case swapping views, was every time the home view reappeared. I moved it into my viewDidAppear function and it's working much more smoothly now. Thank you for guiding me to this realization!

Comment: I was also just wondering, do you know a more efficient way to keep the audio stream on continuously? I'm not sure if a repetitive do-catch statement is too efficient or code-friendly.

Comment: `viewDidAppear` Exactly what I suspected. That can work but you need to use a Bool flag so it only gets called the first time `viewDidAppear` runs.